# Check if the ID of one table is used as a foreign key in another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql database that has two tables:

> GAME (ID, Name)
>
> TICKET (ID, GameID, Section...)

Game.ID is a primary key in GAME, and GameID is used in the TICKET table as a foreign key to know which game it is part of.

I have the sql statement:

> SELECT * FROM GAME ORDER BY Date

It returns all game records from the GAME table. I want a sql statement that will only return the game record if there is at least 1 record using it as a foreign key in the TICKET table, thus only giving me the games that have tickets.

I've tried joining the tables together and checking it that way, but my sql just isn't there yet.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get fancy

```
SELECT * FROM GAME G
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TICKET T
    WHERE G.ID = T.GameID
    )
```

Comment: Love this fancy query, but it unfortunately doesn't provide any of the ticket data which may also be useful since it is required to exist.

Comment: @Rottingham, where have you found that requirement?

Comment: Just an assumption based on the requirement of the Ticket. Not downing your answer at all! Love it

Comment: _I want a sql statement that will only return the game record if there is at least 1 record using it as a foreign key in the TICKET table, thus only giving me the games that have tickets._ - no ticket data required

Comment: Can I pay points to earn Attention? (need to pay attention..) Thanks Leon

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to the actual requirements @leon. I only need it to return the game name once, as stated above. Your "SELECT 1" looks like it's plucking the first one and doing exactly what I need. Better luck next time Rottingham :)

Comment: @NathanFrancy, not really - the `SELECT 1` piece selects *something* so that the DBMS understands that the `EXISTS` is fulfilled. What the query states is *give me all rows on table GAME that have a matching row on table TICKET, by comparing GAME table's ID field and TICKET table's GameID field*. It doesn't matter how many results match the WHERE filter.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM GAME
JOIN TICKET ON GAME.ID = TICKET.GameID
GROUP BY Game.ID
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Using the JOIN clause makes it, in easy to understand terms, require that there but a ticket for that game. It also includes the ticket data. You can add a GROUP BY GAME.ID if there are multiple TICKETS per GAME so that it doesn't show multiple results when it doesn't need to.

Comment: I'm only looking to return the game id and name ONCE per game, if there are tickets in that game. This returns all tickets.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from game g inner join ticket t on g.id = t.game_id
```

That will return one row per ticket (5 tickets to one game will become 5 rows here)...uses an 'inner join' as a filter.

I suspect you are looking for something more like

```
Select * from game where id in (select game_id from ticket group by game_id)
```

This will give you one row per game regardless of number of tickets.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM GAME ,TICKET   where TICKET.GameID  = GAME.ID ORDER BY Date
```